# Ajax called the previous Action in struts2?

Tags: ajax, struts2

Let say I have  jsp pages named **list_question.jsp** and **ajax_result.jsp**

in struts.xml

```
<action name="question/*/*" class="ProcessAction" >
  <param name="selectedCatId">{1}</param>
  <param name="questionId">{2}</param>
  <result name="success">list_question.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="submitReponse" class="AJXAction" >
  <result name="success">ajax_result.jsp</result>
</action>
```

the scenario as follows:

First, the page **list_question.jsp** is displayed as the success result of **ProcessAction**. Everything worked perfectly.

Then, inside **list_question.jsp**, I perform an ajax call as follows:

```
$("#postResponse").click(function(){
                $("#responses").html("loading...");
                $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: "submitReponse", // Action name
                        data: $('form').serialize(),
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#responses").html(data);
                        }
                        }); 
            });
```

The problem is, it never called the **AJXAction** action class, rather it always invoked the previous action class (**ProcessAction**), even though different action names are specified.

I am missing something?

Comment: What's the actual request being sent on the wire? E.g., complete URL etc? Normally you'd want to use something generated by a `<s:url>` tag etc. to get the context etc. and action extension if you're using one.

Comment: do you have any namespace configuration? try http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/config-browser-plugin.html

Comment: It may be a problem of validation of your form's data; try adding an input result (with a static JSP for example) for your AJXAction mapping, and see if it's returned. P.S: "submitReponse" should be "submitResponse", and "AJAXAction" would be preferred to "AJXAction" , for more clarity...

Comment: @Dave Newton: you're right, use <s:url> solved my problem. thanks